# Quarkus Flyway Placeholders Configuration issue

Tags: flyway, quarkus

I am having trouble getting quarkus.flyway.placeholders working in my Quarkus app.
I have this line defined in my application.properties file

```
quarkus.flyway.placeholders.myuser=my_user
```

in my sql file I have this line

```
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON survey.answers TO ${myuser};
```

the error I'm getting is

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No value provided for placeholder: ${myuser}.  Check your configuration!
```

Here are the things I've tried:

1. upgraded to Quarkus 1.13.6.Final
2. Tried setting

```
quarkus.flyway.placeholder-prefix=#[
quarkus.flyway.placeholder-suffix=]
```

As shown in the integration test:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/main/integration-tests/flyway

Thank you
Matthew

Comment: I just tried the examples from the integration test 
```
quarkus.flyway.placeholders.title=REPLACED
quarkus.flyway.placeholder-prefix=#[
quarkus.flyway.placeholder-suffix=]
```
SQL changed to 
```
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON survey.answers TO #[title];
```
New Error message
```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "#"
```

Comment: I just tried the integration test you mention and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a typo in your configuration or sql script.

With the following settings:

```
quarkus.flyway.placeholder-prefix=#[
quarkus.flyway.placeholder-suffix=]
```

In your sql file the placeholder should be defined as a `#[myuser]`, not `$[myuser]`

You can also change the placeholder-prefix definition in your `application.properties` file to support prefix you already have in the sql file.

Answer (score 0):

At one time I have two flyway users.
quarkus.flyway.owner this one has create privileges
quarkus.flyway.user this one has fewer privileges.

This item was not associated with the user role.
quarkus.flyway.placeholders.myuser=my_user

After changing it to quarkus.flyway.owner.placeholders.myuser=my_user
it started working.